# Webstorm doesn't debug .php files in Chrome

Tags: php, webstorm

When I click "debugging"

[image: Webstorm debugging button]

in Firefox I get the result page in html, that I can inspect:

[image: Debugging PHP file in Firefox]

But in Chrome I just get PHP source code:
[image: Debugging PHP file in Chrome]

What is the problem?
Has anyone come across?

Comment: probably firefox is treating it as an html file and all the php code is hidden because it LOOKS like it's html tags. chrome is treating it as plain text and not trying to render any of the tags. You're loading from a `file:///` url, so there is NOTHING executing the php code. what you see in firefox is not output, it's simply all thephp code hidden. try doing a `view source` in firefox and you'll see the php code.

Comment: Why not post as an Answer Marc?

Comment: Marc you are right, there is php code in page source in FF. Thanks! It's a pity that Chrome can't do like FF.

Answer (score 4):

You're accessing the file directly on disk.  Try accessing it through your webserver (in other words, *serve the page as HTML*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will do so, but later. Marc B explains, why is it so